# Display data on table out of bound using Laravel

Tags: php, html, html-table, laravel-5.6

So, Basically the Company can have one, two or no director and I want to display based on the company profile.
I want to display table like below (please don't mind the red border, I just want to highlight what I really want to changed in my table):-
[image: this is what I want]

and this is what I got:
[image: what I actual got]

this is my loop for displaying inside the table:

```
<table class="table table-borderless table-sm table_view2">
  <thead>
   <tr class="spaceSmall">
     <td style="width:50%;padding-left: 10px;">NOTES TO ACCOUNT<br>Schedules referred to above and notes attached there to form an integral part of Balance Sheet.<br>This is the Balance Sheet referred to in our Report of even date.</td>
     <td style="width:25%"></td>
     <td style="width:25%"></td>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr class="spaceSmall">
     <td style="padding-left: 25px;">{{ $auditor->auditor_name }}<br>{{ $auditor->qualification }}<br>Membership No. : {{ $auditor->membership_number }}</td>
    @foreach($tasks->work->company->directors as $director)
     @if($director->pivot->director_type == 'Both' || $director->pivot->director_type == 'Director')
      @if(count($director) == 1)
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ $director->salutation }} {{ $director->first_name }} {{ $director->last_name }}<br>DIRECTOR<br>{{ $director->din }}</td>
      @elseif(count($director) == 2)
        <td>{{ $director->salutation }} {{ $director->first_name }} {{ $director->last_name }}<br>DIRECTOR<br>{{ $director->din }}</td>
      @else
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      @endif
     @else
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
     @endif
    @endforeach
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

If company doesn't have director or if company has 1 director, then it is working perfectly, but if company has 2 directors then it try to insert at the 3rd and 4th column but I don't have that 4th column, If I removed the `if` condition inside that `foreach` then it's displaying like the 1st image but I have to check the `director(s)` they had.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have a look at query scopes https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: yeah, it's good and exciting. but it doesn't really help what I really want here.

Comment: You need to rephrase your question then

Comment: okay, I want to display my table data like the 1st image but when I loop the data from the database and if the count is equal to 2 then I got like the second Image, inside my `foreach-loop` @elseif(count($director) == 2) inside this condition the column cannot fill from the second column but from the third, and it tries to fill another more that's why I got table out of bound. I hope you can understand my English :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, for anyone seeking the answer I just put this line outside the loop then everything works fine.

```
@php $countDirector = count($tasks->work->company->directors); @endphp
```

And inside my `foreach`

```
@if($countDirector == 1)
  <td></td>
  <td>{{ $director->salutation }} {{ $director->first_name }} {{ $director->last_name }}<br>DIRECTOR<br>{{ $director->din }}</td>
@elseif($countDirector == 2)
  <td>{{ $director->salutation }} {{ $director->first_name }} {{ $director->last_name }}<br>DIRECTOR<br>{{ $director->din }}</td>
@else
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
@endif
```